# maximization or minimiation linear optimization

Tags: optimization

I'm just studying for a maths exam I have in a few weeks and the notes my teacher gave me contradict so much on the internet that now I'm really confused.
In his notes he says the standard form of an LPP is a minimization problem and we should change all maximisations to minimizations. Literally all other sources on the internet say the opposite, that the simplex only works for maximisations and to convert the other way. I'm guessing my teacher didn't just write an entire semesters worth of wrong information (I mean maybe he did), so whats going on.
Any information would be very helpful, thanks a million.
P.s He also has a slightly different definition of the standard form which has inequalities and says only the canonical form has qualities, again the internet disagrees, any info on this would also be great.
Thanks

Comment: "Literally all other sources on the internet say the opposite" Check out the problem form used in slide 12-2 [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/simplex.pdf) (Vandenberghe's 236a slides). Any LP phrased as maximizing $c^T x$ can be rephrased as a minimization problem by replacing $c$ with $-c$.

Comment: There is no standard standard form, and some work with standard primal forms vs standard dual forms, and confusion arise.